# Does "would" mean "wanted to" here?

Tags: grammar

[*Romeo and Juliet*, Act 2, Prologue](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/romeojuliet/page_72.html):

> CHORUS
>
> Now old desire doth in his deathbed lie,
> 　　And young affection gapes to be his heir.
> 　　That fair for which love groaned for and **would** die
> 　　With tender Juliet matched, is now not fair.
> 　　Now Romeo is beloved and loves again,
> 　　Alike bewitchèd by the charm of looks,
> 　　But to his foe supposed he must complain,
> 　　And she steal love’s sweet bait from fearful hooks.

What does *would* mean here?  Does it mean the same thing as "wanted to"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about literary analysis of non-contemporary texts. There are many valid answers which are likely to be opinion-based.

Comment: @Tiercelet It's a linguistic question, not one of literary analysis. And in this case the non-contemporary character doesn't enter into the matter - we use *would* in the same sense today.

Comment: @StoneyB I disagree. See http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/would defs 2, 4, and 6 are relevant: the sentence would be perfectly sensible if it meant a) it was going to die; b) it was willing to die; or c) it wanted to die. (and that last one is possible because the language is archaic, e.g. "he would have it so"). Choosing among several grammatically and semantically correct readings with different senses is a literary-analysis task, not a grammatical one...

Comment: @Tiercelet That is not literary analysis in any sort of LitCrit sense. It is discourse analysis, which all linguistics is; how many times a day do we demand more context of our questioners?

Comment: Am I correct in thinking this could be reworded as “love would **die for** that fair”? This is a usage that persists today, though it is presented somewhat poetically here. In that case, “would” could mean either “was/is willing to” or “was going to” depending.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Yes, I think so.  I think that the bigger problem for most speakers of modern English would be the use of the word *fair* here.

Answer (score 1):

From a purely grammatical standpoint, you can't equate "would" with "wanted to". If you say, for example, "I would catch a bullet for you" - you don't imply that you *want* to be killed, only that you would give your life for the other person *if need arises*.

Of course, when analyzing a text from a literary standpoint, you often have to see the broader context and look for hidden meanings of the words (especially with Shakespeare!).

Comment: +1 It might better be paraphrased *was willing to*.